# HTML object tag responsive or full height

Tags: html, height, responsive

I'm sorry but I don't know how fix this scrollbar, 
and set up it with full height about  tag.

[image: This is the object]

Comment: Please add the code. A screenshot of code is not code.

Comment: which code you need?